# Is the cardinality of occuring torsion subgroups in cofinite lattices in SL(2,R) bounded?

Tags: gr.group-theory, riemann-surfaces, lattices

Let $\Gamma$ be a cofinite lattice in $PSL(2,\mathbb{R})$ with torsion subgroup $H$.

Is the a uniform bound on the cardinality of $H$?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are triangle groups $(2, 3, n)$ for any $n>6,$ so I would say the answer is **NO**